# Multiple select statements in OLEDB source ssis

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Using SQL Server Integration Service `(SSIS)` 2008, I created `OLEDB Source`
and filled the `SQL Command` Filed with the following query:

```
select A,B,C from Table1;
select D,E,F from Table2;
```

but I have the **invalid character** error when press the preview button but the query runs perfect on `Oracle SQL Developer`

Comment: Your source query should return a single set.

Answer (score 1):

Just change your command to

```
select A,B,TO_CHAR(C) as C from Table1
union all
select D,E,TO_CHAR(F) as F from Table2;
```

- where `C` and `F` fields have different datatypes

Comment: union all caused this error ORA-01789: query block has incorrect number of result columns
01789. 00000 -  "query block has incorrect number of result columns"

Comment: when selecting the same number of columns this error occured
ORA-01790: expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression

Comment: then check your query again. Here in my answer both `select` statements have exactly three columns. Probably your query in SSIS has different columns in one of these two `select` statements.

Comment: ok, than you need to cast datatypes of corresponding columns to the same. In the most general case to `varchar`

Comment: try to use `TO_CHAR()` function for all columns which have different datatypes (check [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora01790.php))